# Unable to create database in Odoo 13.0

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I've been trying to create a database in Odoo 13.0 Community edition on a local Linux based server using the database manager in localhost:8069, but for some reason I always get the same error.
[*Image of the error in Odoo*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh89i.png)

Here's my Odoo log error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: no existe la relación «ir_model»
LÍNEA 1: SELECT * FROM ir_model WHERE state='manual'
                       ^ - - -
```

Also I have fully uninstalled Postgres and all the config files the same way I did with Odoo.

I tried fixing the installation with the following (by reinstalling and erasing entirely Odoo) without any success:

```
sudo rm -R /opt/odoo

sudo rm -f /etc/odoo.conf

sudo update-rc.d -f odoo remove

apt-get --purge odoo
```

I have followed several ways of uninstalling and reinstalling Odoo to end up being in the same point. I have also tried installing newer versions of Odoo such as Odoo 14.0 and got the same results. What could I try next?

Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

Edit: The installation proccess I followed is [this one](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/es/administration/install/install.html#prepare)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of countless retries I managed to find the source of the error, in case anyone has the same problem I updated and upgraded my server and installed pip3. The root of the problem was the version of LXML, I upgraded it by using

```
pip3 install --upgrade lxml
```

If someone sees this I hope it helps!